# Symfony - полиморфная связь oneToOne по идентификатору

Tags: doctrine2, relation, doctrine-orm, symfony5

Есть клас **Product** и у него есть склад (**WarehouseLocation**), и в его "позиций" **ProductAttitude** может быть склад, так вот, привязка позиции и продукта к складу будет на одну таблицу по идентификатору сущностей, то-есть **id=id**

**Product:**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="WarehouseLocation") //пример
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private ?WarehouseLocation $warehouse;
```

Связи на уровни базы не будет только на уровни кода. Как можно замапить сущность **WarehouseLocation** в атрибуты классов как примеры выше. Мне ненужно работать с сущностями по отдельно, хочу через главную, можно ли такое реализовать в symfony, по тому что в других фреймах такое реализуемо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачку! В подчинённой сущности вписываете поле на которое будет ссылаться главная сущность:

```
// Подченьоный сушность в которой id=id Product 
/**
     * @var Product
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Product",
     *      inversedBy="warehouse", // поле куда будет маписта даный обект в продукт
     *      orphanRemoval=true,
     *      cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private ?Product $product; // null обизательний так как даная сушнности будет пустой если к ней будет обращатса другая главная сушность
```

В главной сущности обяляем поле подчернённой сущности с возможностью записать null или нет в зависимости как вам нужно:

```
Главная сушность Product
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(
     *     targetEntity="WarehouseLocation",
     *      mappedBy="product",
     *      orphanRemoval=true,
     *      cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     */
    private ?WarehouseLocation $warehouse;
```

Дальше заключения, делаем diff миграции и со всего прочего удаляем генерируемую связь где FK равняется id=id, поднимаем миграцию, и теперь добавляем таблицу подчернённую сущность в **doctrine.dbal.connections.default.schema_filter** или туда где у вас производятся настройки фильтра схемы, данный мув был сделан чтобы не было выхлопов в миграцию по связи, а сама связь теперь работает и мы можем флушыть подчиненный объект с главного, не зависимости кому он подчиняется